# Can I change the batch size in a yolo detection model in OpenCV?

Tags: opencv, yolo

I am loading a yolo model with opencv in python with `cv2.dnn_DetectionModel(cfg,weights)`
and then calling `net.detect(img)`.  I think I can get a speed-up per image using batches, but I don't see any support for batch size other than one.

Is it possible to set the batch size?

Comment: Do you want to combine images and pass them to the net?

Comment: @AmirKarami Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`net.detect` does not support batch size > 1.

However, it's possible to do inference with batch size > 1 on darknet models with some extra work.  Here is some partial code:

```
net = cv2.dnn.readNetFromDarknet(cfg,weights)
net.setInputNames(["input"])
net.setInputShape("input",(batch_size,3,h,w))
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImages(image_list)
net.setInput(blob)
results = net.forward(net.getUnconnectedOutLayersNames())
```

Now loop over all the images, and for each layer output in results, extract the boxes and confidences for this image each class, and having collected this info for every layer, pass this through cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes.  This part is non-trivial, but doable.

Answer (score 0):

one idea is you combine images manually and pass it into net and after getting result you separate them:

```
h1, w1 = im1.shape[:2]
h2, w2 = im2.shape[:2]

#create empty matrix
vis = np.zeros((max(h1, h2), w1+w2,3), np.uint8)

#combine 2 images
vis[:h1, :w1,:3] = im1
vis[:h2, w1:w1+w2,:3] = im2
```

after inference, you can sperate them again:

```
result1=pred[:h1,:w1,:]
result2=pred[:h2, w1:w1+w2,:]
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, net.detect simply doesn't support this.